# Restrict number of SSH connections by user name or IP?

Tags: linux, ssh

Can I restrict the number of ssh connections to my Linux box - by username or by ip or both?

Comment: You should probably have a more descriptive title so that people know what you are asking at a glance.

Answer (score 3):

To allow login only some users you can use **AllowUsers** keyword in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
To restrict a number of ssh connections You can use **MaxSessions** keyword.

For example:

```
AllowUsers jack joe
MaxSessions 5
```

From manual:

> AllowUsers
>            This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns,
>   separated by spaces.  If specified,
>   login
>            is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns. 
>   Only user names are valid; a numerical
>            user ID is not recognized.  By default, login is allowed for all
>   users.  If the pattern takes the form
>            USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting
>   logins to particular users from
>   partic-
>            ular hosts.  The allow/deny directives are processed in the
>   following order: DenyUsers,
>   AllowUsers,
>            DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.